# Entity Framework - What is Service layer's role in repository pattern

Tags: entity-framework

Currently, I'm working on an ASP MVC4 project using EF5 with repository pattern. 
I have just joined this project.

In this project, we have implemented many repository class, these repository will responsible for search, update, delete etc using the `dbcontext`, they also return the DTO classes and in the service layer we use those repositories to get the DTO then convert to the view model.

Every time I want to do some logic with the entities, I will go to the repositories and write code here. So I wonder why we need the service layer and the repositories at the same time, we can write the logic code directly in the service layer or use repositories in the controller directly.

I don't see any advantage here since our source code is too complicated and we need so many classes (DTO, viewmodel...) and I think the performance will be not good compare to using repositories or services directly.

Can you point out the key here? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple:

- Repositories are for data access
- Services are for business logic

But once you've started to instill business concepts into repositories it becomes very hard to turn the tide.

An example of how easily business concepts mingle with data access concerns is soft deletes. Let's say that there is a table `journal_voucher` from which rows should never be deleted, only inactivated. So there is a boolean (bit) field `IsActive` that's set to `false` if a row should be off the record.

Now it seems obvious to have a `Delete` method in `JournalRepository` that sets the `IsActive` flag in stead of deleting an entity. Likewise, any retrieval methods may automatically filter out inactive records.

Wrong. Being active or inactive is a business concept. For a data access layer the content of any database field is meaningless. It's only supposed to read and write it properly.

Now see what happens: other entities will probably just be hard-deleted. Maybe yet others can't ever be deleted, or, why not, never be created. If one repository has this active/inactive responsibility, the next obvious step is to implement these other CRUD rules in the appropriate repositories as well. Then a business requirement emerges that only records of the current year are interesting... Oh, and we have to check whether a `journal_voucher` can even be inactivated... And so on and so forth.

You end up with a host of very different repository classes and scattered business logic.

I believe that *if* you decide to use your own repositories on top of Entity Framework's repositories (`DbSet`s) they should be [generic repositories](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). That is: for each entity class they do exactly the same thing. It's even arguable whether they should return DTOs instead of EF entity objects (I'd vote for the latter).

Everything else is done in services. So there will probably be a `JournalService` that inactivates `journal_voucher`s, with proper checking. The service decides that `IsActive` is set to false and instructs the repository to update the entity. (In fact a unit of work should do that, but that's a different story).

This distinction has many benefits:

- The rest of the world only communicates with services.
- Therefore, repositories can safely return `IQueryable`. The services limit the amount of retrieved data.
- It's much easier to decide where business logic involving multiple entities belongs (i.e. almost all business logic).
- It is much easier with dependency injection.
- The repositories can be mocked relatively easily and the services can be readily unit tested without duplicating business rules in mocked repositories.